# Restrict access to WildFly web console for non-local connections

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have troubles finding a reference for allowing access to server console from local connections only.
Is there configurable option / best practice for this? Preferably without disabling web interface  or involving OS / network options for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WildFly only allows local connections by default, so if you get remote management connections, it seems you've changed the defaults already.

This is the relevant section in `standalone.xml`

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Make sure that `jboss.bind.address.management` is set to a local address.

Comment: Thanks, that's the default I got and it works the way you mentioned. I just had that q popping in my head during setup, wasn't quite sure where to look and worded it wrongly when checking google.